# What message do you get when you try to "build and go" an AppStore distribution release using an Adhoc certificate?

Tags: iphone

I know you are not able to "Build and Go" a build for Appstore distribution using the appropriate certificate since it's not tied to a particular device.  What is the actual error message you get when you try to do that?

When I tried to build and go my AppStore distribution, it will attempt to install it on the device and then gave this message: "The executable was signed with invalid entitlements", is that the right message?

Answer (score 0):

I've actually been able to submit my Ad-hoc build to the App Store, and they've approved it. I figured they'd be able to strip off their own DRM to get it prepped for the App Store anyhow; I guess they do. The nice thing about it for me as a dev is I get to build/test the exact binary I'll be shipping off to the App Store.

I can't say it's an approved method, so YMMV.

Or perhaps you were asking something else entirely?